# three.js box3 of a imported sphere

Tags: javascript, object, three.js, 3d

i have a short question:
I know how to calculate the boxes of my (imported) 3dobjects f.e.

var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj);

With this i can compute boxes for my objects and i can merge them together if i want.

The problem is, now i have these 2 objects https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcjw2.jpg

The solution seems quite simple: i need to compute the left and right spherebox and put them together, but both of these 2 objects are imported with stlloader. I'm not sure how stlloader exactly works, (it seems for me like its all 1 huge mesh) so i'm not even sure if this is possible.

so my questions:
1. how can i compute a box with the shape of a sphere of my sphere object.
2. Is this even possible for my stl object? (I will try when i get the answer for question 1)

Edit: Question 1 should somehow be working with .computeBoundingSphere..
is there a way to make this visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. how can i compute a box with the shape of a sphere of my sphere object.

Well, in `three.js` you have the choice between two bounding volumes. `THREE.Box3` represents an axis-aligned bounding box (AABB) whereas `THREE.Sphere` represents a bounding sphere. If you need a *box with the shape of a sphere*, use `THREE.Sphere`.

> 2. Is this even possible for my stl object?

The method `setFromObject()` does only exist for `THREE.Box3`. However, you can compute the bounding sphere via `THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere()`. This sphere is defined in local space, however. You can use `THREE.Sphere.applyMatrix4()` to transform it into world space by passing in the world matrix of the 3D object.

> is there a way to make this visible?

There is no helper class for bounding spheres. But you can easily create a helper mesh based on `THREE.SphereBufferGeometry`. Something like:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( boundingSphere.radius );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.position.copy( boundingSphere.center );
scene.add( mesh );
```

`three.js R109`

Comment: first steps all worked for me. I now need to assign the sphere to my object. sphere.applyMatrix4(obj.matrixWorld) gives me the error: object doesn't support prop. or meth. applyMatrix4.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unable to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/53apnwht/